# How to use relational data on Parse whereWithinMiles function?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, relational-database

i have a Field class which has a pointer to it's "Father" class which is Venue, Venue has a Location column, i want to make a query that only brings Fields that are within 30 miles.

```
query.whereWithinMiles("venueId.Location", userLocation, 30);
```

i'm sure that the mistake is in venueId.Location, but i don't know how to get the value of my pointer's Location column.

venueId is the pointer.
Location is the pointer's column which i want to compare.
userLocation is the user current Location.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot notation is not supported in where queries but only in include .
If you like to do it you will need to write your query with ** whereMatchesKeyInQuery**

so in you case it should look something like that (change the values according to your classes):

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery.getQuery("ParentClass");  // change the class name
ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(40.712784,-74.005941);  // put your location here
query.whereWithinMiles("location",point,30);

ParseQuery venueQuery = new ParseQuery.getQuery("SubClass");  // change the class name
venueQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("venueId","objectId",query);
venueQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

    }
});
```